# Regex correctly groups but python incorrectly inserts values?

Tags: python, json, regex

I'm using regex to parse some text that is formatted as so

```
M/27/6’4” [230lbs to 216lbs] (5 months) 
M/17/5'2" [150lbs to 113lbs] (12 months)
```

this following code prints out the match for me and then inserts it into a dictionary, which is then dumped into a json object.

```
height = re.search(r'[0-9](\'|’)([0-9][\"|”]|[0-9][0-9][\"|”])'  , submission.title)
if height:
    print('height: ' + str(height.group()))
    topics_dict['height'].append(str((height.group())))
```

the print returns the correct value however when I print out the json object I receive respectively

```
"height": [
        "6\u20194\u201d",
        "5'2\""
    ],
```

I think it mostly has to do with how the italicized quotes are printed, just unsure of how to fix it.

Comment: I think this is normal behavior, python is printing out your string as a unicode string, since the quotes of the first string [arent normal quotes](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm).

Comment: If you `import unicodedata` and then normalize the string using: `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', yourstringhere)` and then print it out, it should print out `6’4”`

Comment: so you got me on the right track, the python is printing the unicode for the print but in the json object it is utf-16(technically right). Do you know a way I can convert it or have it inserted as unicode?

Comment: you got that in before I sent mine, thank you so much!

Comment: np ill add it as an answer so you can close this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first strings quotes are unicode quotes, thats why python is printing it out as:

`"6\u20194\u201d"`

If you want to convert it to a normal string(ascii). You can do:

```py
import unicodedata

unicode_string = u"6\u20194\u201d"

print(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', unicode_string))
```

`>>> 6’4”`